# How can I fix the values of column in the next months?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let me start from the problem that I want to solve.

Example of problem:

| id | date | Value to be fixed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1232 | 01.01.19 | 2P |
| 3212 | 01.01.19 | 3P |
| 1232 | 01.02.19 | 1P |
| 3212 | 01.02.19 | 3P |
| 1232 | 01.03.19 | 1P |
| 3212 | 01.03.19 | 2P |

As you can see value of 3rd column in id - 1232 is changed in february, the same thing happened to id - 3212 in march. What I want to do is keep those values constant, hence the same as in first month.

Result I need:

| id | date | Value to be fixed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1232 | 01.01.19 | 2P |
| 3212 | 01.01.19 | 3P |
| 1232 | 01.02.19 | 2P |
| 3212 | 01.02.19 | 3P |
| 1232 | 01.03.19 | 2P |
| 3212 | 01.03.19 | 3P |

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, please can you show us Your code - the code you have tried ?

Comment: Sorry, I did not try anything at all. I can't wrap my mind from where to start.

Comment: Well start at the beginning where else. What do you need to do with your data ? Change them ? What is the other word for "change" the data ? It is update(lets say they are representing the same thing). So, if you want to try something start with an update table statement.

Comment: Values in 3rd column of some unique id might change in new added month in DB or stay the same, but because they are changing, I want to make the same as in the first considered month, in my case it is january.

Comment: I can write more specific conditions of the problem.

Comment: Found the solution, made the mapping of needed columns from first month as new table, and used left join adding column of values from january by keeping them same in consuqent months.

Comment: If you think the solution would be helpful to someone else, post your final query - and the results - as an answer.